# Copy dll.config to a VSIX

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Is it possible to copy dll.config of a project that represents a Visual Studio 2012 extension to a vsix so that it been copied to a folder when installed into VS?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to do this, I simply added this config named {project}.dll.config with build action `Content` and enabled copying to VSIX. But this does not solved my main task - I wanted to enable NLog logging in the VS extension. Logging levels are still all switched off.

Comment: Be careful with .dll.config when it comes to extensions -- if another extension does the same thing, it's not clear which .config wins.

Comment: Thank you, Jason, for this remark, it is rather reasonable. Now I rejected the solution I've described above as it still does not allow me to configure NLog from config, so I came to a solution when I configure logging imperatively in one static class and insert this initialization in every place that can be a starting point from where all extension logic can begin.